# Last.fm's track.getTopTags method, and what it retrieves

Tags: music

I'm interested in using MSD's Last.fm database, but I'm unsure what, exactly, is represented by the tag counts associated with each track.

I know that each track-tag pair corresponds to a number between 1 and 100, but how is this number derived? I need to know if it would be redundant to calculate a measure of association for the tracks and tags.

EDIT:

[Link to the Last.fm Dataset.](https://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/lastfm)

[Link to the track.getTopTags method in Last.fm's API.](http://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getTopTags)

Comment: can you provide a link to this db? what do the docs say?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, [here's the link](https://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/lastfm). I'm having trouble finding any explanation of the 1 to 100 score in any of the docs, or in the Last.fm API.

Comment: why do you think they are between 1-100? offhand, just looks like the number of tags that have been applied to that particular instance. joining the api group throws 500 internal server error. yay!